# Referring member before execution of not trivial constructor

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, language-lawyer

I read c++ 11 draft standard (N3242 revision) and came across on following statement:

> (12.7 Construction and destruction). For an object with a non-trivial constructor, referring to any non-static member or base class of the object
>   before the constructor begins execution results in undeﬁned behavior.

As I understand following default constructor of `Foo` has undefined behaviour (in piece of code `i(&a.i)`?
 Constructor of `Foo` is not trivial (because it is user defined) and I am referring to member `a` before execution of constructor.

```
struct A
{
    int i;
};

struct Foo
{
    A a;
    int* i;
    Foo() : a(), i(&a.i)
    {}
};
```

UPD: maybe usage of member of type `int*` is not so informative(type `int` is more suitable for example)

Comment: _"I am referring to member a before execution of constructor."_ No, you're not. You just constructed it with `a()`. `a.i` is uninitialised, but taking its address is OK.

Comment: What about member `i` of type `int`? Is it okay? I cannot understand meaning of such statement of c++11

Comment: @underscore_d, can you give examples of incorrect reffering please? It really confuses me

Comment: What exactly is your question? Basic types like `int`, `int*`, and so on have trivial constructors, which leave them uninitialised, but they are still constructed enough to perform a limited set of operations (assigning, taking the address) on them. Anyway, think about it: if it was UB to refer to a member in the ctor init list to merely construct it, the language just wouldn't be able to work at all.

Comment: @underscore_d Actually, since `a` is [value initialized](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization) in the constructor initializer list, the value of `a.i` is well-defined to be zero (the whole structure `a` and all its members are value initialized as well).

Comment: @LmTinyToon As for your question, in the constructor initializer list all members *exists* in memory. They may not be initialized, but they do exist as part of the surrounding `Foo` object (in this case).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, okay. Let's `i` has type `int` As I understand, following code will not confirm standard. Am I right?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Ah, right, that must be: _"2) if T is a class type with a default constructor that is neither user-provided nor deleted […] the object is zero-initialized and then it is default-initialized if it has a non-trivial default constructor"_ These are the nuances I forget, but that may be a good thing, as it means if I want value-initialisation, I explicitly code it. :)

Comment: @LmTinyToon Even in that case it's alright, since initialization is in the order the member variables are declared in the class. That means `a` will be fully initialized including `a.i`, so referring to it and using it as a value is okay.

Comment: @LmTinyToon Nothing in your example contradicts your quote from the Standard. Again, if it was illegal for an object to do anything with its own members in its own constructor initialisation list, the language could not exist.

Comment: @LmTinyToon Also, if you read that draft standard, you should also see some *examples* of valid and invalid code.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, examples don't cover this case (Maybe I read standard not very carefully
)

Comment: If they don't cover it, that's probably because it's self-evidently legal, as is clear from other clauses in the Standard. The document can't explicitly show examples of every configuration of code that is OK.

Comment: Maybe because the case you show is considered trivial? Sure it's a bit of a read and it's not all in one place, but with a little research your case *is* one of the "OK" cases (no matter if `Foo::i` is a pointer or not).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, I think you are right. Thanks for replies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> As I understand following default constructor of Foo has undefined behaviour (in piece of code `i(&a.i)`?

No. The wording you cite uses the phrase "before the constructor begins execution." But when we initialize `i` in the *mem-initializer*, we're doing that *after* `a` has already been constructed (since `a` is declared before `i`), so this is perfectly fine.

Moreover, even if the two members were switched, the program would still be fine because `A` doesn't have a non-trivial constructor.

If you look at the examples in that section, they clarify the intent of the wording. Particularly the [second example](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.cdtor#1):

> ```
> struct W { int j; };
> struct X : public virtual W { };
> struct Y {
>   int* p;
>   X x;
>   Y() : p(&x.j) {   // undefined, x is not yet constructed
>     }
> };
> ```

`X` has a non-trivial constructor (because of the `virtual` base), so we refer to `x` before it's been constructed, but the initialization of `p` does just that. Hence, UB.

Comment: As I understand, standard statement refers to constructor of member `a` not  `Foo`?

Comment: @LmTinyToon I don't understand the question. The statement doesn't really apply here at all - it would apply if you were to potentially access a member of `Foo` before that `Foo` object was constructed. Within `Foo`, we don't have any members with non-trivial constructors, so there isn't anything we could do wrong - for the purposes of this clause.